# Why can't we MOV a value of A000H or higher into a 16-bit register?

Tags: assembly, hex, emu8086

I have tried most basic instruction "mov ax,B006H" and got the error message

[image: error message]

Comment: I assume A000H doesn't work and that you really mean 16-bit values greater than or equal to A000h . The rule is that if you using the `h` suffix to denote a hexadecimal number, and value that starts with A, B, C, D, E, F the hex number must be preceded by a 0. Basically if you have a Hex number that begins with a letter (and uses an `h` suffix) you have to tack on a 0 to the beginning.

Comment: It isn't just for 16-bit numbers. Without adding an extra 0 to the beginning for cases where the upper most digit is Ato F the assembler would have no way of knowing if `mov al, ch` means move register CH to AL or whether you meant move the hex value `c` (12 decimal) to AL. To do that you'd have to write `mov al, 0ch` .

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hexadecimal numbers must start with a *decimal* digit.  That is why so many hex constants start with a leading zero.

This will work:

```
mov ax, 0b006h
```

Comment: mov ax, 0b006h worked also mov ax, 0xb006h works too.

Comment: What do you mean be `even`? Oh you didn't mean "even" (as in evenly divisible by 2). For clarity I'd strike the word `even`

Comment: @Basilisk if you use `0x` prefix don't put `h` on the end. Although EMU8086 supports that most other assemblers including MASM/TASM will give an error. Either use `0x` prefix or `h` suffix but not both.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: It means that for the assembler to recognize a token as a numeric literal, it has to start with a digit, but *even* for hex numbers it has to be a decimal digit, not any hex digit.  I think I mentally parsed it that way the first time I read it, but after seeing your comment it took me a few seconds for my brain to parse it correctly again. :P

Comment: @PeterCordes : Yeah in my comment  suggested they consider striking the word `even` for clarity.

Comment: @MichaelPetch:  Great suggestion.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
mov ax,0B006H
```

the parser is picky

Comment: This is the older answer by 10 seconds.

Comment: Older, but slightly less detail about why the parser is picky.  In your answer it's left to the reader to work out why a leading 0 is necessary here.  (Obvious if you think about how you'd write a parser / the ambiguity with symbol names, but not everyone will easily come up with that reasoning.)

Comment: @PeterCordes: I couldn't work out why because the assembler I used couldn't handle a symbol name there, but only [symbolname], so I though the parser was picky for no good reason.

Comment: I'm curious what assembler you use; in both major flavours of Intel syntax (NASM and MASM), `mov ax, symbol` is valid.  In NASM, it's a mov-immediate of the address.  In MASM-like assemblers it's a load from the symbol address, same as `mov ax, [symbol]`

Comment: @PeterCordes: I learned on Borland C++'s asm {} blocks before I got a real assembler.

Comment: @PeterCordes:  I wrote quite a bit of 80x86 assembler code which didn't require any futzing (like using `ifdef` or whatever) for the code to assemble with both `masm` and `tasm`.

Comment: @wallyk:  I was including TASM in the MASM-like flavour group.  They even use similar directives I think, unlike GNU gas `.intel_syntax noprefix` which is also MASM-like but uses completely different directives outside of instruction lines.